# injected service is not being identified in the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
var login_app = angular.module('login_app',[]);


login_app.factory('login_service', function($http) {
   return {
        login: function() {
             //return the promise directly.
             return $http.get('/service/login')
                       .then(function(result) {
                            //resolve the promise as the data
                            return result.data;
                        });
        }
   }
});  

login_app.controller('login_controller',
                    ['$scope',
                     function($scope,login_service){

                      $scope.login_username = "";
                      $scope.login_password = "";
                      $scope.remember_login = false;
                      $scope.login_button_action = function(){
                                                    login_service.login();
                                                 }

                    }]);
```

I have a login form which is under the scope of this controller and works fine.
whenever I press the login button, login_button_action is getting called via ng-click directive.

```
my problem is that I keep getting this error in my JavaScript console.

ReferenceError: login_service is not defined
```

Is there something wrong with the wya my controller is using the service ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the login_service to the definitions above:

```
login_app.controller('login_controller', ['$scope','login_service',
    function($scope,login_service){
        // Your code using the service.
}]);
```

And of course...the service script file needs to be linked in the document.

To be complete...you do not have to do this at all if you are not considering minification or such. In that case it can just be

```
 login_app.controller('login_controller', function($scope, login_service){
      // Your code using the service.
 }]);
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! so to be clear, should the name of the variable used as an argument in the controller should match the string as it is, or its the order that matters ?

Secondly, all of it is in one file. If I put service in a different fileof its own, how do make sure that service gets defined before the controller uses it?
Will I have to include all the files in that order in the html page ?
or there is an angular way of accomplishing this ?

Comment: Order matters, and the name that is defined as string must match the actual service. The object reference can be whatever you like but it's a best practice to keep it the same.

Comment: If you place them in seperate files you need to make sure they are loaded before the angular application is instantiated. For your info; take a look at a library called RequireJS. Is solves this kind of issues.